# Definition of multiple integration of complex-valued function of several real variables

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, definition

As a reader of *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, the following notation bothers me:
[image]

The last line computes the **surface integral over a complex-valued function of several real variables**. If it were Lebesgue integration, many standard contexts tell that the integration is to be interpreted as the sum of integral of real part and $i$ times integral of imaginary part. But if it were differential forms with underlying Riemann integration, I can't see in any context the standard definition. (Though I can imagine that the definition is also to separate the real and imaginary part.)

Please tell me the context from where I can read the exact definition of the integration. Or in which way I can truly understand the integration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{U} f \,dx \wedge dy$ means the same as $\int_{U} f \,d(x, y)$. The right hand side is a Lebesgue integral, and $f$ can be complex valued, or even $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued without a problem.